# How to calculate total hours from multiple in time and out time from below?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Below is my table sturture]

first punch as in time,
second punch as out time

if possible avoid duplicate punch on same time within a minute

I need to get all in time ,outtime in a row with total hours
like below any format.

I tried below query but can't get my expected output

```
WITH  Level1
                  AS (
                        SELECT  A.emp_reader_id,

                                               DT
                         ,A.EventCatId
                         ,A.Belongs_to
                         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.Belongs_to,A.emp_reader_id  ORDER BY DT ) AS RowNum 
                       FROM dbo.trnevents A  


                     )
                   , 
                  LEVEL2
                  AS (-- find the last and next event type for each row 
                       SELECT A.emp_reader_id,A.DT , A.EventCatId ,COALESCE(LastVal.EventCatId, 10) AS LastEvent,
                                                                COALESCE(NextVal.EventCatId, 10) AS NextEvent ,A.Belongs_to
                       FROM Level1 A 
                               LEFT JOIN Level1 LastVal 
                                  ON A.emp_reader_id = LastVal.emp_reader_id and  A.Belongs_to=LastVal.Belongs_to
                                     AND A.RowNum - 1 = LastVal.RowNum 
                               LEFT JOIN Level1 NextVal 
                                  ON A.emp_reader_id = NextVal.emp_reader_id and  A.Belongs_to=NextVal.Belongs_to
                                     AND A.RowNum + 1 = NextVal.RowNum 
                     )
                     select * from level2 where emp_reader_id=92 order by dt desc
```

Expected output:

[image: sq]

Comment: Please **do not use images** instead post sample data as _formatted text_ as you did to your code or much better as DDL and DML.

Comment: What is the indication for In and Out time?

Comment: @mkRabbani first punch as in IN, and second punch as out.

Comment: 29th has only 1 row?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, if its one then consider as only in -- he miss out punch

Comment: 3 records between 1 min - 15.58.27, 15.58.38 and 15.59.00. They all should consider as duplicate as per your logic. But you neglect just one. Why?

Comment: @mkRabbani yes all duplicate need one from duplicate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535990/sum-time-fields-in-below-query -sort this final stage

Answer (score 1):

Try this below script. I considered all DT with Sam Minutes as single entry for the calculation.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT MAX(emp_reader_id) emp_reader_id,
    CAST(DT AS DATE) Date_for_Group,
    LEFT(CAST(DT AS VARCHAR),16) Time_For_Group,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(DT AS DATE) ORDER BY LEFT(CAST(DT AS VARCHAR),16)) RN,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(DT AS DATE) ORDER BY LEFT(CAST(DT AS VARCHAR),16))%2 = 0 THEN 'OUT' 
        ELSE 'IN' 
    END In_Out
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY CAST(DT AS DATE),LEFT(CAST(DT AS VARCHAR),16)
)

SELECT A.emp_reader_id,A.Date_for_Group,
SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute,CAST(A.Time_For_Group AS DATETIME),CAST(B.Time_For_Group AS DATETIME)))/60 Hr,
SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute,CAST(A.Time_For_Group AS DATETIME),CAST(B.Time_For_Group AS DATETIME)))%60 Min
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B 
ON A.emp_reader_id = B.emp_reader_id
AND A.RN = B.RN -1
AND A.Date_for_Group = B.Date_for_Group
WHERE A.In_Out  = 'IN'
GROUP BY A.emp_reader_id,A.Date_for_Group
```

Answer (score 1):

first assign rownumber to datetime column then start the same result set with rownumber+1
Then Inner join them on rownumbers. After that select min an max from timein and out columns and group by on date to get total workhours of that day. hope it helps.

```
 select empid
  ,date
  ,min(timein) as timein,max (timeout) timeout,convert(nvarchar(20),datediff(hh,min (timein),max(timeout))%24) 
  +':'+
  convert(nvarchar(20),datediff(mi,min (timein),max(timeout))%60) as totalhrs
from(
Select a.empid,cast(a.dt as date) date,b.dt as timein,a.dt as timeout from(
SELECT  DT
  ,[empid]   
  , id
  ,row_number() over(order by dt) as inn
FROM [test1].[dbo].[Table_2]
)a
inner join(
SELECT distinct DT
  ,[empid]
  , id
  ,rank() over(order by dt)+1 as out
FROM [test1].[dbo].[Table_2])b
on FORMAT(a.dt,'hh:mm') <> FORMAT(b.dt,'hh:mm') 
and cast(a.dt as date)=cast(b.dt as date) 
and a.inn=b.out)b
group by b.empid,b.date
```