# sum time fields in below query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum working time in a day from below query

> Below is my query:

```
WITH Level1
           AS (-- apply row numbers 
               SELECT emp_reader_id , 

                      CAST(dt AS DATETIME) AS [DATETIME] , 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_reader_id 
                                  ORDER BY dt ) AS RowNum 
              FROM trnevents 
              ), 
        LEVEL2
           AS (-- find the last and next event type for each row 
              SELECT   A.emp_reader_id , 
                       A.DATETIME ,                       
                       COALESCE(NULL, 'N/A') AS LastEvent , 
                       COALESCE(NULL, 'N/A') AS NextEvent 
              FROM Level1 A 
                   LEFT JOIN Level1 LastVal 
                      ON A.emp_reader_id = LastVal.emp_reader_id 
                         AND A.RowNum - 1 = LastVal.RowNum 
                   LEFT JOIN Level1 NextVal 
                      ON A.emp_reader_id = NextVal.emp_reader_id 
                         AND A.RowNum + 1 = NextVal.RowNum ), 
        Level3 
           AS (-- reapply row numbers to row-eliminated set 
              SELECT  emp_reader_id ,

                      DATETIME ,                      
                      LastEvent , 
                      NextEvent , 
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_reader_id 
                          ORDER BY DATETIME ) AS RowNBr 
              FROM Level2              
              ), 
        Level4
           AS (-- pair enter and exit rows. 
               SELECT A.emp_reader_id , 
                      A.DATETIME , 
                      B.DATETIME AS ExitDATETIME 
               FROM Level3 A 
                    JOIN Level3 B ON A.emp_reader_id = B.emp_reader_id 
                                     AND A.RowNBr + 1 = B.RowNBr               
               ), 
        LEVEL5 
           AS (--Calculate the work session duration 
               SELECT emp_reader_id , 

                      DATEDIFF(second, DATETIME, ExitDATETIME) 
                               AS Seconds , 
                      DATETIME , 
                      ExitDATETIME 
               FROM Level4
              ) 

SELECT emp_reader_id , 

          CAST([DATETIME] AS date) AS [dt],
          CAST([DATETIME] AS Time) as [In], 
          CAST(ExitDATETIME AS Time) As Out,  
          RIGHT('0' +   CAST(Seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' 
          + RIGHT('0' +   CAST(Seconds % 3600 / 60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' 
          + RIGHT('0' +   CAST(Seconds % 3600 % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
                               AS TotalHours 
   FROM Level5
```

i tried sum fields it showing error

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts
>   separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff
>   with a less precise datepart.

And my output is look like below

[image: Output]

> Expected Output:

[image]

Any other solutions are also welcome with better execution time and efficient query.

Kindly help one me to sort out this

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support times > `23:59:59.9999999`; if you *must* show these values as a time, you will have to use a `varchar(8)`

Comment: i not asking same i facing stuggle on above query to group by date @MajidAzarniush

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, your problem is here:

```
DATEDIFF(second, DATETIME, ExitDATETIME) AS Seconds,
```

I say "obviously" because this is the only `datediff()` in the table.

I'm pretty sure your data is at fault.  But you can fix the problem ("paper it over") by using `datediff_big()`:

```
DATEDIFF_BIG(second, DATETIME, ExitDATETIME) AS Seconds,
```

This returns a `bigint` rather than an `int`, so it won't overflow.

I would recommend finding the culprit, by doing something like this:

```
SELECT emp_reader_id, 
       DATEDIFF(day, DATETIME, ExitDATETIME) AS days, 
       DATETIME, ExitDATETIME 
FROM Level4
ORDER BY days DESC;
```

`days` should not overflow with `datetime` values.  You will see the culprits and can fix the data.